# Can I use a custom recordmapper in JOOQ select field already?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Suppose I have a custom RecordMapper due to whatever reaons:

```
    public class UserGroupMapper implements RecordMapper<Record, UserGroup> {
        @Override
        public UserGroup map(Record rec) {
            UserGroup grp = new UserGroup(rec.getValue(USER_GROUP.ID),
                    rec.getValue(USER_GROUP.NAME),
                    rec.getValue(USER_GROUP.DESCRIPTION)
                    javaParseTags(USER_GROUP.TAGS)
            );
        }
```

In JOOQ, I could use it like so:

```
ctx.select()
                .from(USER_GROUP)
                .fetch(new UserGroupMapper());
```

However, if I want to select multiple things (like data from a left join), it would be convenient to not use the RecordMapper in the last step (fetch step) but already during the `select` step as I have seen as an example here with POJOs, not RecordMappers: `ctx.select(row(A, B, C).mapping(MyPojo::new), otherFieldsLikeMultiSet)`

My question: Is there something like this syntax available for normal RecordMappers as well? The `mapping` function expects a FunctionN<AllMyFields..., ?> and not something like Function<Record, ?> as the RecordMapper implements.

So some code somewhat like this:

```
UserGroupMapper mapper = new UserGroupMapper(); //Implements RecordMapper

var res = ctx.select(
      row(
         USER_GROUP.ID,
         USER_GROUP.NAME,
         USER_GROUP.DESCRIPTION,
         USER_GROUP.TAGS
      ).mapToMyPojo(mapper), // this function doesn't exist. How to utilize my mapper here? 
      USER_GROUP.JSONLOAD
   )
   .from(USER_GROUP)
   .fetch();
```

Now, I'd like to have a `Result<Record2<UserGroup,String>>`. So instead of using the recordmapper "in the end" at fetch phase, I'd like to apply the RecordMapper earlier. I know it's possible when providing a FunctionN to the row object `mapping`, but my RecordMapper sadly isn't a `FunctionN` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Row4.mapping(Function4)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Row4.html#mapping(org.jooq.Function4)) is just syntax sugar for [ad-hoc conversion methods](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/), like [`SelectField.convertFrom`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SelectField.html#convertFrom(java.util.function.Function)).

Now, `Row4<T1, T2, T3, T4>` extends `SelectField<Record4<T1, T2, T3, T4>>`, and thus you can pass any `? super Record4<T1, T2, T3, T4>` type to the `convertFrom(...)` method. Your `RecordMapper<Record, UserGroup>` extends `Function<Record, UserGroup>`, so you can pass that directly:

**With jOOQ 3.17**

```java
Field<UserGroup> field = row(...).convertFrom(new UserGroupMapper());
```

**With jOOQ 3.16**

The above `SelectField::convertFrom` method was pulled up from `Field` only in jOOQ 3.17, see [#13118](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13118). Prior to that, you can turn your `row()` expression into a `Field` using `DSL.field(SelectField)`:

```java
Field<UserGroup> field = field(row(...)).convertFrom(new UserGroupMapper());
```

Comment: Ah OK, so the reason that this is not working for me is that my RecordMapper simply implements <Record>, not <Record7>.. I thought, it wasn't possible at all.

Comment: @Theo Your `RecordMapper` accepts a super type of the expected `Record[N]` type, so it's less type safe, but you guarantee via signature that you can handle any `Record` subtype.

Comment: And there isn't a `convertFrom` on the `row()`  :( (JOOQ 3.16.6) Only this mapping function which doesn't acceppt my RecordMapper

Comment: Ah yes, it was pulled up from `Field` to `SelectField` only in jOOQ 3.17.0: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13118. But there's a 3.16.x workaround, which I'll add to the answer